# sql error when adding joins options and conditions

Tags: sql, cakephp

I made this query in cakePhp to get count with conditions and inner joins but I found error like this :

> SQL Error: 1064: Syntax Error near 'inscriptions_reducs registered INNER WHERE `Registration`.`seance_id` = 5402 AND` Insc' in line 1

this is my query:

```js
$countInscri = ClassRegistry::init('Inscription')->find('count',array(
'joins'=>array(
            'table'=>'inscriptions_reducs',
            'alias'=>'insc',
            'type'=>'INNER',
            'conditions'=>array('insc.inscription_id = Inscription.id')
            ),

'conditions'=>array('Inscription.seance_id'=>$value['Seance']['seance_id'],
                    'Inscription.is_confirmed is not null',
                    'Inscription.canceled is null',


                    'NOT'=>array('insc.reduction_id'=>array(1,2,22))
                    )
));
```

Comment: don't post image  .. post text code ..  so who want  answer  can avoid to rewrite your code  ..

Comment: it's ok Im sorry ..

Comment: The `joins` array is ment to be an array of arrays (sets of join configurations), see **https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables**.

Comment: thank you @ndm it's working but it need more time to give result !

Comment: Note sure what exactly you mean by "_more time to give result_", but if you're referring to the time required for executing the query, that's surely possible, make sure that you're columns are properly indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join param needs to be an array of arrays:

```
'joins' => array(
    array(
        'table'=>'inscriptions_reducs',
        'alias'=>'insc',
        'type'=>'INNER',
        'conditions'=>array('insc.inscription_id = Inscription.id')
        ),
    )
)
```